# on changes to grid view to link xml layout shows log cat error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, logcat, android-logcat

I have changed the log cat with the new error.Log-cat error is again showing the same error and emulator gets close forcefully after clicking on date in calender...
I have even declared all activity in manifest then too error continues....
Please help out

```
12-11 11:31:05.745: W/dalvikvm(483): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.examples.android.calendar/android.util.EventLog$Event}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView$4.onItemClick(CalendarView.java:104)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-11 11:31:05.755: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 11:31:08.927: I/Process(483): Sending signal. PID: 483 SIG: 9
```

The code which contains error is in grid view on click listener is as follows.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        TextView date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.date);

                         LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        if(date instanceof TextView && !date.getText().equals("")) {

                     //    Intent intent;

                            String day = date.getText().toString();
                            if(day.length()==1) {
                                day = "0"+day;
                            }
                            // return chosen date as string format 
                        /** intent.putExtra("date", android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM", month)+"-"+day);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                            finish();
                            */

                            //Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Event.class);

                           Intent intent = (new Intent(CalendarView.this, Event.class));               
                           startActivity(intent);



                               // RelativeLayout layoutLeft = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
                                 //   R.layout.event, null);


                        }

                    }
                });
            }
```

This is my projects manifest file which i have updated with  some changes.....

**Manifest** File

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"> 
            <activity android:name=".CalendarViewSampleActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
             </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView"
              android:label="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView"> </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarAdapter"
            android:label="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarAdapter" > </activity>

         </application>
```

I have added complete code of my project please verify the code. The onclick event to call new xml layout from gridview shows an error.

To view Calender here is the code.

**CalenderView.java file**

```
        package com.examples.android.calendar;
        public class CalendarView extends Activity {

            public Calendar month;
            public CalendarAdapter adapter;
            public Handler handler;
            public Context context;
            public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store some random calendar items

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
                month = Calendar.getInstance();
                onNewIntent(getIntent());

                items = new ArrayList<String>();
                adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);

                GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

                handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(calendarUpdater);

                TextView title  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));

                TextView previous  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.previous);
                previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(month.get(Calendar.MONTH)== month.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH)) {                
                            month.set((month.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1),month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH),1);
                        } else {
                            month.set(Calendar.MONTH,month.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1);
                        }
                        refreshCalendar();
                    }
                });

                TextView next  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next);
                next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(month.get(Calendar.MONTH)== month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH)) {                
                            month.set((month.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1),month.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH),1);
                        } else {
                            month.set(Calendar.MONTH,month.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
                        }
                        refreshCalendar();

                    }
                });


                gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        TextView date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.date);

                         LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        if(date instanceof TextView && !date.getText().equals("")) {

                        //  Intent intent = new Intent();

                            String day = date.getText().toString();
                            if(day.length()==1) {
                                day = "0"+day;
                            }
                            // return chosen date as string format 
                        /** intent.putExtra("date", android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM", month)+"-"+day);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                            finish();
                            */

                            //Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Event.class);

                        Intent intent = (new Intent(CalendarView.this, Event.class));             
                         startActivity(intent);



                               // RelativeLayout layoutLeft = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
                                 //   R.layout.event, null);


                        }

                    }
                });
            }

            public void refreshCalendar()
            {
                TextView title  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

                adapter.refreshDays();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             
                handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some random calendar items               

                title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
            }

            public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
                String[] dateArr = date.split("-"); // date format is yyyy-mm-dd
                month.set(Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]), Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
            }

            public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    items.clear();
                    // format random values. You can implement a dedicated class to provide real values
                    for(int i=0;i<31;i++) {
                        Random r = new Random();

                        if(r.nextInt(10)>6)
                        {
                            items.add(Integer.toString(i));
                        }
                    }

                    adapter.setItems(items);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
        }
```

This event fle is to be called by gridview.This file has to be displayed after clicking on date in calender.... 
**event.xml file**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Event Date"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <android.widget.Space
                        android:id="@+id/space1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Event Discription"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Emulator is being forcefully stopped show error in this java file
**CalenderViewSampleActivity.java** file

```
        package com.examples.android.calendar;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.DatePicker;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class CalendarViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */

            static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
            static final int PICK_DATE_REQUEST = 1;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openButton);

                openButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),CalendarView.class);

                        intent.putExtra("date", dp.getYear()+"-"+dp.getMonth()+"-"+dp.getDayOfMonth());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_DATE_REQUEST);              
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (requestCode == PICK_DATE_REQUEST) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.getStringExtra("date"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String[] dateArr = data.getStringExtra("date").split("-");
                        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
                        dp.updateDate(Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]), Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

**CalenderAdapter.java file**

```
        package com.examples.android.calendar;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.GridView;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            static final int FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK =0; // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1


            private Context mContext;

            private java.util.Calendar month;
            private Calendar selectedDate;
            private ArrayList<String> items;

            public CalendarAdapter(Context c, Calendar monthCalendar) {
                month = monthCalendar;
                selectedDate = (Calendar)monthCalendar.clone();
                mContext = c;
                month.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
                refreshDays();
            }

            public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
                for(int i = 0;i != items.size();i++){
                    if(items.get(i).length()==1) {
                    items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
                    }
                }
                this.items = items;
            }


            public int getCount() {
                return days.length;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                TextView dayView;
                if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

                }
                dayView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.date);

                // disable empty days from the beginning
                if(days[position].equals("")) {
                    dayView.setClickable(false);
                    dayView.setFocusable(false);
                }
                else {
                    // mark current day as focused
                    if(month.get(Calendar.YEAR)== selectedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) && month.get(Calendar.MONTH)== selectedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) && days[position].equals(""+selectedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_background_focused);
                    }
                    else {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
                    }
                }
                dayView.setText(days[position]);

                // create date string for comparison
                String date = days[position];

                if(date.length()==1) {
                    date = "0"+date;
                }
                String monthStr = ""+(month.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
                if(monthStr.length()==1) {
                    monthStr = "0"+monthStr;
                }

                // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array

                return v;
            }


// refresh days of month .


            public void refreshDays()
            {
                // clear items
                items.clear();

                int lastDay = month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int firstDay = (int)month.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                // figure size of the array
                if(firstDay==1){
                    days = new String[lastDay+(FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK*6)];
                }
                else {
                    days = new String[lastDay+firstDay-(FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK+1)];
                }

                int j=FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK;

                // populate empty days before first real day
                if(firstDay>1) {
                    for(j=0;j<firstDay-FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK;j++) {
                        days[j] = "";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for(j=0;j<FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK*6;j++) {
                        days[j] = "";
                    }
                    j=FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK*6+1; // sunday => 1, monday => 7
                }

                // populate days
                int dayNumber = 1;
                for(int i=j-1;i<days.length;i++) {
                    days[i] = ""+dayNumber;
                    dayNumber++;
                }
            }

            // references to our items
            public String[] days;
        }
```

Comment: can you post your androidmanifest.xml file and code which you have wrote..

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <activity android:name=".CalendarViewSampleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView">
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarAdapter">
       </activity>
    </application>

Comment: I have posted the answer..

Comment: please help me out to sort out this problem i have even cleaned  the project.

Comment: I have updated code and new log cat error

Answer (score 1):

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.examples.android.calendar/android.util.EventLog$Event}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

You might opening another activity onItemclick of your gridview. Your logcat shows that you forget to register your activity in your manifest file. Make sure you have declared your activity in your manifest file.

**EDITED:**

You are redirecting to the `Event` class on `onItemClicklistener` and you have not declared your `Event` activity in your manifest file. Declared it in your Manifest file.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"> 
        <activity android:name=".CalendarViewSampleActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
     <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
         </activity>

     <activity android:name=".Event"> </activity> //Declared this line in your manifest.

     </application>
```

Also remove the Adapter class which your have declared in your manifest. `<activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarAdapter"> </activity>` Adapters are never declared in manifest.

Comment: The required code which is manifest that you have not posted. And also you have removed the logcat. Why ?

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"><activity android:name=".CalendarViewSampleActivity" 
android:label="@string/app_name"><intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter></activity><activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView"
android:label="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView"></activity><activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarAdapter"
></activity></application>

Comment: Can you update your question with the new logcat error and with some relevant code which contains error ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have resisted then try to place in correct way,.

I think **You have declared your activity outside application tag**.

I think it will work..

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"> 
    <activity android:name=".CalendarViewSampleActivity" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
 <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
     </activity>

 <activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView"
      android:label="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView"> </activity>

 <activity android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarAdapter"
    android:label="com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarAdapter" > </activity>

 </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException" Excpetion...which means you haven't put your Activity in Manifest...